# ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'mail_admins'

Tags: python, django

I have a problem whenever i create a new virtual environment
`conda create --name enc django`
It create an virtual env for me but whenever i tried to run my server, it throws this error. I have also downloaded django in my system from and when i run this command, it runs successfully but whenever i create a virtual environment it throws this error.
I couldn't figure out how to resolve this error or is this a bug?

````
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\logging\config.py", line 563, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\logging\config.py", line 744, in configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\log.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.reporter_class = import_string(reporter_class or 'django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter')
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.views.generic.base import View
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.views.generic.dates import (
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\dates.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.views.generic.detail import (
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 164
    class DetailView(SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseDetailView):
                                                                       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\Scripts\django-admin-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\startproject.py", line 20, in handle
    super().handle('project', project_name, target, **options)
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\templates.py", line 113, in handle
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\log.py", line 71, in configure_logging
    logging.config.dictConfig(DEFAULT_LOGGING)
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\logging\config.py", line 808, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "C:\Users\amurt\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\logging\config.py", line 570, in configure
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'mail_admins'```
````

Comment: Not sure if you resolved this, but I just ran into the error while running migrations.  I had to change the order of my setting imports and then also use a get_model() function on a Model to avoid circular imports.

Comment: I tried going through the [version history on GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/detail.py), but I can't find any evidence that the code `class DetailView(SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseDetailView):` was ever (as reported in the stack trace) on line `164` of the file in question (`django\views\generic\detail.py`). This doesn't appear to be reproducible.